# REGEX Simple Pattern

Tags: sql, regex, presto

I am trying to create a regex pattern that follows the pattern `Quote + 6 digits + Quote` i.e.

- `"123456"`
- `"789456"`
- `"456456"`

---

```
REGEXP_LIKE(String, '\"\^[0-9]{6}$\"\') as reg
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong? My end goal is to simply return the % where this equals `FALSE`

Comment: Your `^` and `$` boundaries are misplaced. `^` matches the beginning of the input and `$` matches the end. It's not possible that `"^` matches given `^` will never be the beginning of input.

Comment: thanks for the fast re's - just now trying to learn regex. Mighty confusing at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
where regexp_like(string, '^"[0-9]{6}"$')
---------------------------^ begins with
----------------------------^ "
-----------------------------^ digit
----------------------------------^ 6 of'em
-------------------------------------^ "
--------------------------------------^ end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
where regexp_like(string, '^"\d{6}"$')
```

Rationale:

- you don't need to escape the double quote - the regex engine understands it just as what it is: a literal double quote
- the beginning and end of the sring (resp `'^'` and `'$'`) must be placed at the very beginning and end of the pattern
- `'[0-9]'` can be shortened as `'\d'`

Comment: Does the `d` just stand for digits here?

Comment: It's basically an alias for `[0-9]`.

Comment: @urdearboy: `\d` means "match a digit character, i.e. 0-9". It's equivalent to the POSIX regular expression class `[[:digit:]]`. You can see how the regex `^"\d{6}"$` is evaluated by looking at the explanation pane at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/x7zRD7/1)

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for explaining how this works. Being new, I like the [0-9] approach so it's clear what is going on although I can see how the `d` approach is prob used by more regex seasoned users